# What is React.AsyncComponent class?

Tags: facebook, reactjs

When I was going through the source code of [React](https://github.com/facebook/react), I came across a base class called "[AsyncComponent](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/faa4218632ca21f3af731fb6c14849fc054fca15/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L141)". This is new to me unlike popular base classes "Component" and "PureComponent". I was wondering what it was and if, how & where it is being utilized to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

It is an alternative to using the static class property `unstable_asyncUpdates`. Everything inside has async updates by default.

As I understand it, you can achieve the same result using 
`ReactDOM.deferredUpdates`.

But the main problem is that async rendering is not ready yet and it will become available later.

Quote from Release notes to v16:

> We think async rendering is a big deal, and represents the future of React. To make migration to v16.0 as smooth as possible, we’re not enabling any async features yet, but we’re excited to start rolling them out in the coming months. Stay tuned!